Suddenly errors in picamera2
When I use a script I've been using for a couple of years to capture pi camera images, using picamera2 and v3 camera, it does not work.  I get the following
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/previews/null_preview.py", line 29, in thread_func
    callback(picam2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/previews/drm_preview.py", line 75, in handle_request
    picam2.process_requests(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 1164, in process_requests
    display.render_request(display_request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/previews/drm_preview.py", line 66, in render_request
    self.render_drm(self.picam2, completed_request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/previews/drm_preview.py", line 145, in render_drm
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to reserve DRM plane")
RuntimeError: Failed to reserve DRM plane


I ran the same script I've been running for a couple of years. I expected to capture two images (which happened) I get a lot of error messages as listed.
